# Cakephp 1.3: Strange behavior with select box. Find list doesn't work, and find all works strangely

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The table Cs_grpusu specifies the areas in my office. The table Users has a foreign key to Cs_grpusu

Cs_grpusu model (cs_grpusu.php):

```
<?php
class CsGrpusu extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Cs_grpusu';
    var $useTable = 'Cs_grpusu';
    var $primaryKey = 'grpusu';
    var $displayField = 'desgrp';
}
?>
```

Cs_grpusu controller (cs_grpusus_controller.php):

```
<?php
class CsGrpususController extends AppController {
    var $uses = 'Cs_gprusu';
}
?>
```

Cs_grpusu table content:
[image: Table content]

And in my User model I set this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(        
    'Cs_grpusu' => array(           
        'className'    => 'cs_grpusu',            
        'foreignKey'    => 'area'        
    )    
);
```

Now I'll put these areas in my User add.ctp view form:

```
echo $form->input('area',array('type' => 'select','options'=>$group));
```

Until now I think it's OK. Now the problems. If in my user controller I fill the "group" in this way:

```
$this->set('grupos',$this->User->Cs_grpusu->find('all'));
```

My select box options became strange like this (and, debugging, I get the error that I'll describe next):

[image: strange select box]

Now, if I try to fill the group variable like this:

```
$this->set('grupos',$this->User->Cs_grpusu->find('list', array('fields'=>array('Cs_grpusu.grpusu','Cs_grpusu.desgrp'))));
```

No options appear in my select box and I also get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: cs_grpusu [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_firebird.php, line 455]

CONTEXT

$results    =   resource
$num_fields =   2
$index  =   1
$j  =   0
$column =   array(
    "GRPUSU",
    "name" => "GRPUSU",
    "GRPUSU",
    "alias" => "GRPUSU",
    "CS_GRPUSU",
    "relation" => "CS_GRPUSU",
    "2",
    "length" => "2",
    "SMALLINT",
    "type" => "SMALLINT"
)

CODE:

$column = ibase_field_info($results, $j);
            if (!empty($column[2])) {
                $this->map[$index++] = array(ucfirst(strtolower($this->modeltmp[strtolower($column[2])])), strtolower($column[1]));
```

So, what should I do to have my select box only with the options "Reception, Budget..." whithout those strange numbers, and without the undefined index error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Naming your model class "Cs_grpusu" is the first mistake you are doing, it should be "CsGrpusu". All classnames are CamelCased in CakePHP. Read the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/902/File-and-Classname-Conventions) about file and class naming conventions.

Comment: Ok thank you! I changed it but now I'm getting the error "Error: Database table cs_grpusus for model CsGrpusu was not found." although I'm using "var $useTable = 'Cs_grpusu';" in my model. Should I change anything else?

Comment: This means your model filename or classname is still not as per conventions and your class isn't being loaded. If you do `debug(get_class($this->CsGrupusu));` in your controller it will give output "AppModel" instead expected model name "CsGrupusu".

Comment: Make sure you fix the class name in your associations too in User model and elsewhere.

Comment: If I use the model file name as csGrpusu.php the useTable is ignored. But if I use cs_grpusu.php the useTable is used. So I guess in my case cs_grpusu.php should be the correct choice, no?

Comment: The answer your question will be obvious if you actually read the manual page I linked above. Sorry mate but I not going to repeat here what's already there in the manual.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I renamed the file that was cs_grpusu.php, when actually, the manual says that this file name is the correct one. My mistake was only at the model class name as you said, which was Cs_grpusu and now it is CsGrpusu. But it's not working anyway... one more information, although using find('all') brings some strange options for my select box, the error "Notice (8): Undefined index:" also appears.